# Javascript - Selected image not being displayed

Tags: javascript

In my JS file, I check when a user selects a file, and I display this image in the browser. I then allow a user to remove the selected image, and instead an image of a default image is displayed in the browser.

The issue I have is that once a user **removes** the image by clicking the remove text, they are then unable to select a file they want. This is unexpected.

**HTML**:

```html
// Label for file input (file input is generated in backend)
<label id="complete-signup-photo-label" for="complete_signup_photo">Choose a profile photo</label>

// Image displayed in browser(should display image user selects from file input above)
<img id="complete-signup-photo-img" width="40px" height="40px" src="{% static 'default-profile.png' %}" alt="">
// User should be able to click, and src of selected file changes to a default image
<span id="complete-signup-remove-photo">Remove</span>
```

My **JS** file:

```js
img = $("#complete-signup-photo-img");

// This is my file inputs id (generated in my backend)
$("#complete_signup_photo").change(function(e) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

    img.attr('src', url);
});

$("#complete-signup-remove-photo").click(function(e) {
    img.attr("src", "http://localhost:8000/static/default-profile.png"); 
});
```

Anybody know why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: where is file input?

Comment: did you get error in console?

Comment: try to add `console.log(url);` before line `img.attr('src', url);` to check if `change` event is triggered

Comment: @Çağrı The file input is generate in my backend once the page is loaded.

Comment: @Yukulélé I get no errors in the console.

Comment: @Yukulélé Also when I do `console.log(url);`. I get returned `blob:http://localhost:8000/dd5d0ca4-5549-40eb-88c8-4dbdde90f93c`

Comment: @Yukulélé However note that this is printed **only once**, and this is when a file is **first** selected on my page. After that, this message is not printed anymore.

Comment: what is happening to file input after remove image ?

Comment: do you select the same file or another?

Comment: @Çağrı Nothing it stays on the page, however I have made a discovery. When I click the **remove** text, the name of the file the user just removed is still next to the **choose file button** for the input, suggesting the file is still selected. Do you think this is what's causing the issue or does this not make a difference?

Comment: @Yukulélé  I have made a discovery. When I click the remove text, the name of the file the user just removed is still next to the choose file button for the input, suggesting the file is still selected. Do you think this is what's causing the issue or does this not make a difference? –

Comment: @Yukulélé Do you know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did u try to initialize file input?

```
$("#complete-signup-remove-photo").click(function(e) {
    img.attr("src", "http://localhost:8000/static/default-profile.png"); 
    $("#complete_signup_photo").val("");
});
```